# Adding dots in a bar plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data:

```
ggplot(df3, aes(x=Condition, y=readout, fill= Condition, width= 0.8))+geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge())+geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=readout-sd, ymax=readout+sd), width=.2,                position=position_dodge(.9))+ theme_classic()+theme(legend.position="none")+scale_fill_grey()+  labs(x=" ", y="Absorbance, arbitrary units")+ scale_y_continuous(limit = c(0,0.45))
```

[image]

and I need to add the experimental groups plus their replicates in to that plot as dots (six dots in total per group). These dots should be located along the error bars. However, I have never done that before.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I got it

I used this command:

> ggbarplot(ToothGrowth, x = "dose", y = "len",
> add = c("mean_se", "jitter"))